# Are you able to draw lines on top of an image view but have them linked to the image view?

Tags: android, imageview, draw

I have an ImageView that is interactive (tap and pinch zoom + click dragging) and would like to draw lines on the image displayed. If I draw lines onto the ImageView will it be saved onto the image and be transformed by the interactivity or will it be separate and stay the same as the image is changed? I know this may not be understandable, but I can't explain it any other way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom drawable that uses your image?  That way you could draw whatever you want in the draw(Canvas c) method.  You could also override onBoundsChanged to determine what to do when the size of your drawable changes.

Comment: What do you mean by custom drawable?

Comment: Write a class that extends android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.  Look for the Canvas and Drawables section of the online Android documentation for more info.